# Find and delete non empty folder older than 3 day

Tags: linux, find, rm

I want to find and delete non empty directories greater than 3 days.

```
find . <Path> -mtime +3 -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```

I want to delete directories that have files in it and the directory and files are older than 3 days.

```
/tmp
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov  6 05:05 20191106
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov  7 05:05 20191107
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov  8 05:05 20191108
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov  9 05:05 20191109
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov 10 05:05 20191110
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov 11 05:05 20191111
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov 12 05:05 20191112
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov 13 05:05 20191113
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 05:05 20191114
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov 15 05:05 20191115
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov 16 05:05 20191116
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov 17 05:05 20191117
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov 18 05:05 20191118
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Nov 19 05:05 20191119
```

So here greater than 3 days dir. Each directory has some text file.

Comment: And what is the question or problem?

Comment: am unable to find and delete non empty folders.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani: Well for starters that command would delete both files and directories.  It also doesn't have any logic to specify that the directory is not empty.  Finally I believe the `{}` wont work when quoted.

Comment: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d` will return all all nonempty directories. From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/815693/2152558

Comment: @user383228: It's generally best to put more information in your question.  Simply saying it doesn't work is of very little use.  We normally want to know what about it doesn't work.  Does it give an error?  Does it not delete enough?  Does it delete too much?  Etc.  Also since the find command can vary greatly from distribution to distribution it's probably best to include your find version.

Comment: Please define "empty". All directories at level 1 only? When dirs at level 1 are filled with empty subdirs, what should happen? When a dir has only non-empty subdirs and they are deleted, what about the then empty dir?

Comment: My Scenario is i want to delete directory which are having files in it and the directory and files are older than 3days. My path /tmp -----> 20191122, 20191121,20191105. So i want to delete 20191105 folder which is not empty from the /tmp path.

Comment: @user383228 It seems like you are replying to questions that haven't been asked, and not replying to the questions that have been asked.  Also please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/317100) your question to include details about your question rather than comment, as comments will eventually be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Could be something like this:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d -mtime +3 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This solution will delete level 1 non empty directories who hasn't been `touch`ed for more than three days.

Please backup your data before testing.

Comment: Note that `-mtime +3` is _at least 4 days old_

Comment: You could also mention that unless the `-daystart` option is specified, the `-mtime` specification amounts to `n*24 hours` starting _now_ (imagine running the script at 23:00), which may not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

In the `zsh` shell, the non-empty directories in `/tmp` with a modification timestamp of more than three days ago would be matching the filename globbing pattern

```
/tmp/*(/DNFm+3)
```

The glob qualifier `(/DNFm+3)` means

- Only match directories (`/`; this is not strictly needed as the `F` qualifier would imply the same),
- Allow matching hidden names (`D`; works like the `dotglob` shell option in `bash`),
- Expand to nothing if there is no match (`N`;  works like the `nullglob` shell option in `bash`),
- Only include "full" (non-empty) directories (`F`),
- Only include entries that has a modification timestamp of *strictly* more than three days ago (`m+3`; for directories, this means that there was last something added or removed from the directory that many days ago; like for `find`'s `-mtime +3`, that means ***4** days old or older*).

To list all the matches, use

```
print -rC1 -- /tmp/*(/DNFm+3)
```

To delete them, use

```
rm -rf -- /tmp/*(/DNFm+3)
```

If there are several thousands of such matches and you're running into *argument list too long* errors, then use a loop:

```
for dirpath in /tmp/*(/DNFm+3); do
    rm -rf -- $dirpath
done
```

Or use `zargs`:

```
autoload zargs
zargs -- /tmp/*(/DNFm+3) -- rm -rf
```

Or enable the `rm` builtin with `zmodload zsh/files` which will work around that limitation of the `execve()` system call.